# MySQL with Entity Framework on .NET 7

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, .net-7.0

I have the following packages installed:

- "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" 7.0.0
- "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" 7.0.0
- "MySql.EntityFrameworkCore" 7.0.0-preview5+MySQL8.0.31

I have my context file class:

```cs
namespace API.Context
{
    public class EventContext : DbContext
    {
        public EventContext(DbContextOptions<EventContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Property> Property { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Event> Event { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Event>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.ID);
                entity.Property(e => e.Title).IsRequired();
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Property>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.ID);
                entity.Property(e => e.Key).IsRequired();
                entity.Property(e => e.Value).IsRequired();
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Event)
            .WithMany(p => p.Properties);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And my Program.cs:

```cs
using API.Context;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<EventContext>(x => x.UseMySQL(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

My problem is that when I run the command:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

I get this error:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.IModelInitializedConvention> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ConventionSet.get_ModelInitializedConventions()'.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure you use right nuget? - try `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 7.0.0-alpha.1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have the following packages installed:
> ...
>
> - "MySql.EntityFrameworkCore" 8.0.22

No, you don't, you have [`MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore), which is a legacy package which does not support .NET 7.

For .NET 7 support you need either install preview version of [`MySql.EntityFrameworkCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.EntityFrameworkCore/7.0.0-preview5) (latest - `7.0.0-preview5`) or alpha version of [`Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/7.0.0-alpha.1) (latest - `7.0.0-alpha.1`)

**UPD**

Pomelo package was used.

> The following versions of MySqlConnector, EF Core, .NET (Core), .NET Standard and .NET Framework are compatible with published releases of `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`:

| Release | Branch | MySqlConnector | EF Core | .NET (Core) | .NET Standard | .NET Framework |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [7.0.0-alpha.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/7.0.0-alpha.1) | [master](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/tree/master) | >= 2.2.0 | 7.0.x | 6.0+ | - | - |
| [6.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/6.0.2) | [6.0-maint](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/tree/6.0-maint) | >= 2.1.2 | 6.0.x | 6.0+ | - | - |
| [5.0.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/5.0.4) | [5.0-maint](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/tree/5.0-maint) | >= 1.3.13 | 5.0.x | 3.0+ | 2.1 | - |
| [3.2.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/3.2.7) | [3.2-maint](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/tree/3.2-maint) | >= 0.69.10 < 1.0.0 | 3.1.x | 2.0+ | 2.0 | 4.6.1+ |

Comment: You are correct. Now I am using the correct package, but I am just getting a different error :( I have updated the question.

Comment: @Neigaard the source of the issue can be the same - preview packages can have breaking changes, try downgrading other ef packages to preview 5 version.

Comment: @Neigaard I mean other EF Core packages.

Comment: @Neigaard I see two EF Core packages there. Try the Pomelo MySQL. Despite it being alpha, it was recently published, so potentially it is upgraded to the release version of EF Core.

Comment: Switched to Pomelo package worked

Comment: This isn't a matter of legacy vs current Pomelo packages. One package (the one with the problems) is published by Oracle, the other by Pomelo which always worked. Oracle's provider had a lot of problems that weren't getting solved and in the end they simply abandoned their older NuGet for a new one. Which is still worse than Pomelo

Comment: This is an issue with Oracle's nuget package, it still does not work with the preview version and there is no released version which works with .net 7 either. Better switch to other providers for mysql than waste your time.