# Adding migration doesn't work and gives no useful error message

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mariadb

I'm using EF 6.0.12 and when adding migrations to my project, basically this happens:

Visual Studio:

> PM> add-migration Initial
> Build started...
> Build failed.

CLI:

> D:\myproject\db>dotnet-ef migrations add Init
> Build started...
> Build succeeded.
> Unable to create an object of type 'RequestContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Which is as useful as a brick in my face. It gets me really annoyed. And I have no clue on how to solve this as there's no useful error message...
Now, I use these packages in my project:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Version 6.0.12
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools Version 6.0.12
- Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql Version 6.0.2

And my DBContext is inside a Class library, and is used by a Web API. Which works quite well, but I now need migrations.
The problem is that my database is MariaDB and the MySQL package I need does not support .NET 7.0, nor do I use 7.0 so the EF7 packages are off-limits. But my problem is that I just don't know how I can even start finding the cause of this problem. So, where do I start to try and make this work?

---

I've tried to solve things by migrating the project to .NET 7.0 and now use the latest packages:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 7.0.1
- MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.7

These are all the latest versions. And Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql has been removed. Still, it changes nothing about the error I get.
Some more changes made to the code and finally got past this error in the CLI and VS. I now have this exception:

```
PM> add-migration Katje-Init
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalStrings.get_NoConnectionOrConnectionString()'.
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.MySQLOptions.GetConnectionSettings(MySQLOptionsExtension relationalOptions)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.MySQLOptions.Initialize(IDbContextOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SingletonOptionsInitializer.EnsureInitialized(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IDbContextOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<GetOrAdd>g__BuildServiceProvider|4_1(IDbContextOptions _, ValueTuple`2 arguments)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<>c.<GetOrAdd>b__4_0(IDbContextOptions contextOptions, ValueTuple`2 tuples)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TArg](TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.GetOrAdd(IDbContextOptions options, Boolean providerRequired)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
   at RequestDatabase.RequestContext..ctor(DbContextOptions`1 options) in D:\Projects\DB\Datamodel.cs:line 16
Etc...
```

The CLI gives the same exception now. Not sure how I fixed the previous error, but it's still very unclear. So again, what is the best approach to solve these complex errors?

Comment: Just checking. For Visual Studio try selecting correct startup project (Web API) and default project for package manager console (the class library). For `dotnet` - if you are running from the root sln folder provide `--project PathToClassLibFolder` (or `-p ...`) and `--startup-project PathToTheWebApiProjFolder` (or `-s ...`, see  the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options))

Comment: @GuruStron Yep. I've done quite a few projects with additional data migrations but never got a situation where the error is just "Build failed.". The connection string is even set in the OnConfiguring() method. I also migrated the whole project to .NET 7.0 by replacing Pomelo with the Oracle provider and moving all EF packages to the latest build. Still the same useless error.

Comment: AFAIK Oracle one is not very good. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74466530/mysql-with-entity-framework-on-net-7/74467283#74467283). Try using preview version of Pomelo for .NET 7.

Comment: @GuruStron Upgrading to the Pomelo preview finally fixed things.

Comment: Glad it helped! Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last error shows that there is breaking change (usually sign of a version mismatch between the packages). As in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74466530/mysql-with-entity-framework-on-net-7/74467283#74467283) - switch from Oracle MySQL package to Pomelo preview one for .NET 7.

Comment: Done that. Finally got it to work. But I'm still dealing with annoying issues while using a minimal API with migrations.